# Lots of warnings and errors instead of my WordPress site - Synology NAS - Intranet

Tags: errors, warnings

I have been attempting to setup a company intranet on a Synology NAS.
When I came back into work this morning after the weekend instead of the web page there are several pages of warning/error text in the web browser (included below).
The last thing I was doing Friday was trying different themes.

When I search portions (because it's a lot) of the text I see, I find some other people who have similar warnings. However, they all say the text shows up "in the admin area" of their WordPress site. I cannot access the site at all, I just see all this text(below).

I am using a manual install of WordPress from wordpress.org, which I installed just the other day after deciding using the one on the Synology DSM package center meant that all the tutorials/help I could find on the internet didn't really apply to that setup.

I did notice that occasionally when I tried a theme similar text would appear in the preview area, but when I closed the preview it would go back to normal.

This is my first attempt to make a WordPress website, or indeed any website of any complexity. I am simply the resident geek at work who gets tasked with these things so I'm not experienced in these matters at all.

Anyone have any ideas?

If your idea happens to be ask wordpress.org, that was my idea too. I wanted to post this same question on the wordpress.org forum, but when I create an account there I can't log in to it :( so I'm trying to figure that out too :)

Here comes the text dump!

Ok it's way beyond the character limit, here comes a small portion of the text dump!

**Warning: ftp_nlist() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php on line 420 Call Stack: 0.0001 364592 1. {main}() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/index.php:0 0.0001 365328 2. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/admin.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/index.php:10 0.0001 365808 3. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-load.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/admin.php:34 0.0001 366496 4. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-config.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-load.php:50 0.0001 367880 5. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-settings.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-config.php:96 0.0396 3218848 6. do_action($hook_name = 'after_setup_theme') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-settings.php:595 0.0396 3219224 7. WP_Hook->do_action($args = [0 => '']) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 0.0396 3219224 8. WP_Hook->apply_filters($value = '', $args = [0 => '']) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:332 0.0396 3222264 9. car_repair_mechanic_setup('') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 0.0399 3226816 10. car_repair_mechanic_font_url() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/functions.php:69 0.0400 3243200 11. wptt_get_webfont_url($url = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&family=Kalam:wght@300;400;700&family=PT+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600', $format = ???) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/functions.php:236 0.0402 3245888 12. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_url() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:695 0.0402 3245888 13. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->local_file_exists() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:142 0.0402 3245888 14. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_local_stylesheet_path() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:523 0.0402 3245888 15. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_fonts_folder() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:484 0.0402 3245888 16. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_base_path() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:576 0.0410 3256712 17. WP_Filesystem_Base->wp_content_dir() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:535 0.0410 3256712 18. WP_Filesystem_Base->find_folder($folder = '/volume1/web/wphd/wp-content') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php:77 0.0410 3257088 19. WP_Filesystem_FTPext->exists($path = '/volume1/web/wphd/wp-content') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php:229 0.0410 3257088 20. ftp_nlist($ftp = NULL, $directory = '/volume1/web/wphd/wp-content') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php:420 Warning: ftp_pwd() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php on line 230 Call Stack: 0.0001 364592 1. {main}() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/index.php:0 0.0001 365328 2. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/admin.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/index.php:10 0.0001 365808 3. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-load.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/admin.php:34 0.0001 366496 4. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-config.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-load.php:50 0.0001 367880 5. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-settings.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-config.php:96 0.0396 3218848 6. do_action($hook_name = 'after_setup_theme') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-settings.php:595 0.0396 3219224 7. WP_Hook->do_action($args = [0 => '']) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 0.0396 3219224 8. WP_Hook->apply_filters($value = '', $args = [0 => '']) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:332 0.0396 3222264 9. car_repair_mechanic_setup('') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 0.0399 3226816 10. car_repair_mechanic_font_url() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/functions.php:69 0.0400 3243200 11. wptt_get_webfont_url($url = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&family=Kalam:wght@300;400;700&family=PT+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600', $format = ???) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/functions.php:236 0.0402 3245888 12. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_url() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:695 0.0402 3245888 13. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->local_file_exists() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:142 0.0402 3245888 14. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_local_stylesheet_path() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:523 0.0402 3245888 15. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_fonts_folder() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:484 0.0402 3245888 16. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_base_path() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:576 0.0410 3256712 17. WP_Filesystem_Base->wp_content_dir() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:535 0.0410 3256712 18. WP_Filesystem_Base->find_folder($folder = '/volume1/web/wphd/wp-content') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php:77 0.0410 3257088 19. WP_Filesystem_FTPext->exists($path = '/volume1/web/wphd/wp-content') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php:229 0.0411 3257088 20. WP_Filesystem_FTPext->is_dir($path = '/volume1/web/wphd/wp-content') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php:422 0.0411 3257088 21. WP_Filesystem_FTPext->cwd() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php:450 0.0411 3257088 22. ftp_pwd($ftp = NULL) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php:230 Warning: ftp_pwd() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php on line 230 Call Stack: 0.0001 364592 1. {main}() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/index.php:0 0.0001 365328 2. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/admin.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/index.php:10 0.0001 365808 3. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-load.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-admin/admin.php:34 0.0001 366496 4. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-config.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-load.php:50 0.0001 367880 5. require_once('/volume1/web/wphd/wp-settings.php') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-config.php:96 0.0396 3218848 6. do_action($hook_name = 'after_setup_theme') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-settings.php:595 0.0396 3219224 7. WP_Hook->do_action($args = [0 => '']) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 0.0396 3219224 8. WP_Hook->apply_filters($value = '', $args = [0 => '']) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:332 0.0396 3222264 9. car_repair_mechanic_setup('') /volume1/web/wphd/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 0.0399 3226816 10. car_repair_mechanic_font_url() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/functions.php:69 0.0400 3243200 11. wptt_get_webfont_url($url = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&family=Kalam:wght@300;400;700&family=PT+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600', $format = ???) /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/functions.php:236 0.0402 3245888 12. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_url() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:695 0.0402 3245888 13. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->local_file_exists() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:142 0.0402 3245888 14. Car_Repair_Mechanic_WPTT_WebFont_Loader->get_local_stylesheet_path() /volume1/web/wphd/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/wptt-webfont-loader.php:523 0.0402 3245888 15.**

Comment: Have you tried deactivating and reactivating each of your plugins, one by one? There may be a conflict with one of them.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without being able to access the admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very tough to tell exactly what the issue is from only this PHP warning, but it seems to be related to the `car_repair_mechanic_setup()` function within your theme. Since you can't reach the admin of your website, I'd suggest changing the name of the folder on your server at `/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic/`. That should allow you to access the admin of your site again by disabling your current theme.

If you need to use that theme, another potential step would be to turn on debug logging. That will store errors and warnings in a file, instead of showing them directly in the browser. You can read all about this at https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/, but you'll generally want the code in `wp-config.php` that outlines your site's approach to debugging to look like this:

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Please keep in mind that this debugging configuration shouldn't be used on a production server since it may be viewable by anyone on the web.

Neither of these steps will solve your root problem, but hopefully they make it easier for you to access the admin of your site and debug the issue.

Comment: Awesome, this got me to the admin page. For clarification he means change the name of the theme folder, in my case "/wp-content/themes/car-repair-mechanic" to anything else, I changed it to "/wp-content/themes/DISABLED_car-repair-mechanic . I then restarted my NAS for good measure and was then able to access the admin dashboard.  Thank you @jg314

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my answer @hderic. It's great to hear you were able to access the site again.